# Cost function based on inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: matlab, math

I have two points named as `source` and `target`. I know the coordinates of source (e.g, `[-1 1]`) and the problem is determining the location of target (e.g, `[1 -1]`).
[image]

I have some measurements, one of them is the angle of the arrow pointing from target to the source (i.e, `135 deg`).

In order to find the location of target, I define an error function to minimize; I'm using gradient descent algorithm, so I have a symbolic error function like;

```
syms xs ys xt yt
z(xs,ys,xt,yt) = theta - asin((ys - yt)/((xs - xt)^2 + (ys - yt)^2)^.5);
```

In which `theta` is the measured angle, `135 deg` (for an ideal solution `z`, the error, would be zero, `135 - 135 = 0`)

there are other measurements and I calculate the Jacobian of these error functions and minimize the error.

Anyhow, the problem is that `theta` in this example is `135 deg`, but as we know the output for `asin` is `[-90 90]` and for this example it is `asin(1/2^.5) = 45 deg`. So for the right answer, my error function, `z`, won't be zero and I need to change my error function, what should I use?

I simply need an error function for my `theta` varying over `[0 360]`, while `asin` and `atan` have the range of `[-90 90]` and I can't use `if` statements because of symbolic functions.

Comment: Think in terms of vectors and operations like dot product; I think it'll go better.

Comment: Do you not have to square your cost function as well in order to ensure that you will find a minimum? I wonder what your cost function is and the gradient of that cost function? I think you should subtract the gradient of the cost function i.e. `theta- d/dt)`.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about Matlab as well, I'm afraid.

Comment: Use `atan2` instead of `asin` to get rid of the phase ambiguity? Something like `z = theta - atan2(ys - yt, xs - xt);`

Comment: @kkuilla yes I square it later, but for now my problem is the right function. Thanks

Comment: @LuisMendo I considered `atan2` but it's not defined for `sym` arguments, I get error. Right now I'm using `theta = asin(sin(theta));` but in this way I'm actually losing some info, and it doesn't seem efficient. Thanks.

Comment: Try `(cos(theta) - (xs-xt)/((xs - xt)^2 + (ys - yt)^2)^.5)^2 + (sin(theta) - (ys-yt)/((xs - xt)^2 + (ys - yt)^2)^.5)^2`. This is the same as `(cos(theta) - cos(phi))^2 + (sin(theta) - sin(phi))^2;`, where `phi` is the angle defined by the arrow from target to source. This gives `0` for `theta==phi` only. It corresponds to the squared length of the chord between the two angles. You could normalize to [0,1] taking `sqrt(...)/2`

Comment: @LuisMendo, It seems to work well. Thanks for your time, I would accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Kamtal Glad it worked. I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `phi` denote the angle of the arrow from source to target. You want an error function that is non-negative and unimodal, with value zero for `theta==phi` only.

This criterion is satisfied by the function

```
z = (cos(theta) - cos(phi))^2 + (sin(theta) - sin(phi))^2;
```

or equivalently, using `xs`, `ys`, `xt`, `yt` instead of `phi`,

```
z = (cos(theta) - (xs-xt)/((xs - xt)^2 + (ys - yt)^2)^.5)^2 + ...
    (sin(theta) - (ys-yt)/((xs - xt)^2 + (ys - yt)^2)^.5)^2;
```

This error function has the following interpretation: if the angles `theta` and `phi` are represented as points in the unit circle, `z` is the *squared length of the chord* joining those two points.

Of course, the error could be defined in terms of length (instead of squared length) by simply applying `sqrt` to the expression above; and could be normalized between `0` and `1` by then dividing by `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab defines `sym/atan2(Y,X)`

[image: scr]

If not you can create it with

```
function [ theta ] = atan2( dy,dx )
%ATAN2 Four Quadrant Arc Tangent Function
%
    if dx>0
        theta = atan(dy/dx);
    elseif dx<0
        theta = atan(dy/dx)+sign(dy)*pi;
    else
        theta = sign(dy)*pi/2;
    end

end
```

Finally you get to use it like

```
z = theta - atan2(ys - yt, xs - xt);
```

as @LuisMendo pointed out.

**update**
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) mentions that

```
atan2(y,x) = 2*atan(y/(sqrt(x^2+y^2)+x));
```

Comment: I think `atan2` for symbolic variables is only available in recent versions. For example, R2010b doesn't support it. I like this approach though